# Removing an element from a list and a corresponding value

Tags: python, random

```
myList = ['a', 'b', 'c']
myOtherList = [1, 2, 3]
```

If I chose one element from `myList`, how do I remove the corresponding value from `myOtherList`. I am choosing elements from `myList` at random and need to make sure the corresponding value from `myOtherList` is removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to pick an index at random from `myList`.

```
from random import randint

myList = ['a', 'b', 'c']
myOtherList = [1, 2, 3]

index = randint(0, len(myList)-1)

del myList[index]
del myOtherList[index]
```

But if you are stuck with picking an item, just get the index of the item with the... `index` function!

```
index = myList.index(chosen_element)
```

Comment: This picks the position at random, but I am selecting an element from `myList` at random and want the corresponding element in `myOtherList` removed

Comment: Then get the index of the chosen item `index = myList.index(picked)`

Comment: right, cant believe I forgot that. Your solution got me thinking in that direction. Edit and I will accept

Answer (score 0):

Pick the item, then zip the lists so that they are corresponding, for example

```
listA = [1,2,3,4]
listB = [a,b,c,d]

joinedlist = zip(listA,listB)

indexpick = randomindexpicker()  # lets assume that this is '2'

del joinedlist[indexpick]

listA, listB = zip(*joinedlist)
```

This should give you

```
listA = [1,2,4]
listB = [a,b,d]
```